# Sending email from a Django app hosted on Heroku with attachment stored in AWS S3

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

So I want to send an email from Django/Python hosted with Heroku with an attachment (PDF) located in an S3 bucket. So I can send an email with a file attachment that is locally stored but I can't find a way to attach a remotely hosted file to an email.

As an additional point, I'm trying to use Mandrill but this isn't the main requirement.

I'm simply trying to send an email from python/django with an attachment without having to save the attachment locally first (as this isn't recommended/possible/ideal with my Heroku setup)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple enough, assuming your file is stored as a normal file field (with a different storage selected), then you can do the following:

```python
message = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, bcc=recipient_list)
message.attach(FILENAME, mymodel.myfilefield.read())
```

This will just download the file from S3 temporarily into the memory and send the email with the attachment without the necessity to use the local filesystem.

Comment: Docs for EmailMessage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage

Comment: Thanks @rafadeb - worked like a charm once I installed django-storages.